# Невозможно протетстировать rest api при помощи rest template

Tags: rest, spring-boot, resttemplate

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
class ReadTargetControllerImplTest {

    private ResponseEntity<String> response;

    private String responseBody;

    @Test
    void getInfoAboutCity() {

        String urlString = "http://localhost:8080/town/berlin";

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);

        response = restTemplate.exchange(urlString, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);

        HttpStatus statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
        System.out.println("statusCode" + statusCode +"\\");

        responseBody = response.getBody();
        System.out.println("responseBody" + responseBody +"\\");

    }
}
```

вот rest

```java
  @GetMapping("town/{town}")
    public TargetDto getDataAboutCity(@PathVariable String town) {

        System.out.println(town);
        return targetReadService.readEntry(town);

    }
```

> org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8080/town/berlin": Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

**update**

[Вот пример, который помог решить задачу](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/spring-resttemplate-api-testing/)

Какие у кого есть идеи, почему не работает ?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите протестировать веб-слой приложения, то необязательно делать настоящие http-запросы к приложению, достаточно использовать аннотацию WebMvcTest и понадобится проинициализировать в контексте и нижележащий слой сервисов (репозитории нужно замокать)

Это самый простой сценарий и ваш класс будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = ReadTargetControllerImpl.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ReadTargetControllerImpl.class, TargetReadService.class})
public class ReadTargetControllerImplRightTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    //нужно позаботиться об инжекте класса сервиса
    //а также о моках нижележащих репозиториев/сервисов
    private TargetReadService productService = new TargetReadService();

    @Test
    public void getInfoAboutCity() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/town/berlin")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

В свою очередь, если вы таким образом хотите протестировать сервисный слой, то проверять контроллер нет нужны - тестируйте только классы сервисов, мокая классы репозиториев.